# JavaScript Localization in Laravael

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, localization

I am using `Laravel Framwork` for my `php` software and I ran into an issue with localizaing the text within the `JaveScript` files.

I have a database value that sets the `locale` of each user.

`App::setLocale(Auth::user()->lang)` in the `Middleware` folder. It works as expected on the different `blades` using either `@lang('file.name')` or `trans('file.name')`.

For my `JavaScript` files I am using [this method](https://medium.com/@serhii.matrunchyk/using-laravel-localization-with-javascript-and-vuejs-23064d0c210e). It works fine, but it seems that it doesn't update the `locale` based on the value in the middleware, but based on the locale value in `config/app.php`.
The `php` pages all work and update according the the database value.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in the [link that you provided](https://medium.com/@serhii.matrunchyk/using-laravel-localization-with-javascript-and-vuejs-23064d0c210e) is that it will get all the translations for current language and it will cache that forever. So even though you are changing languages, `/js/lang.js` will always return same cached response.

While it is good idea to cache the response of reading all translation files for language, when you create the cache you need to do that per language and to use unique cache key per language (look at the code)

```
// Localization
Route::get('/js/lang.js', function () {

    $minutes = 10;
    $lang    = App::getLocale();

    // each language it will be cached with different key
    // example: "en.lang.js", "fr.lang.js", ...
    $strings = Cache::remember($lang.'.lang.js', $minutes, function() use ($lang) {

        $files   = glob(resource_path('lang/' . $lang . '/*.php'));
        $strings = [];

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $name           = basename($file, '.php');
            $strings[$name] = require $file;
        }

        return $strings;
    });

    return response('window.i18n = ' . json_encode($strings) . ';')
              ->header('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
})->name('assets.lang');
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Nik if you add a new line to translation files or you update existing translation, you have to remember that you won't see changes immediately. In my example I've put 10 (minutes), but you can tweak that, you can move the value in config file or even .env

Comment: @Nik Also, I would recommend passing the language in the `Route::get('/js/{language}/lang.js', function($language) {` as your next problem will be browsers caching **lang.js** file. And then you will have the same problem - that language doesn't change... so maybe consider updating the logic